# Pass information from Parse to the TableiewController

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have an issue when I'm trying to pass the information from the database from Parse to my TableViewController. I think that is the way I'm calling to the name and password.

When I push the View Users button the app crash.

I put my git if you need more information. https://github.com/emmanuelcu/ParseProject.git

class TableViewController: UITableViewController{

```
var dataParse:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var count:Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    //PFQuery
    let query = PFQuery(className: "LoginCredentials")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]? , error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if(error == nil){
            print("The current number of users is \(objects!.count)")
            self.count = objects!.count
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    //return self.dataParse.count
    return self.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "CellData"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.password.text = dataParse[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String
    cell.name.text = dataParse[indexPath.row]["user"] as? String

    print("Error")
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run your query you never assign your objects to your data source, only the number of objects that you receive. Also you're force unwrapping that count without checking if objects has a count, which is possible even without an error.

Answer (score 0):

It works like this dataParse array is empty you should populate it, or should disable view users button when it is empty etc.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "CellData"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...
    if dataParse.count > indexPath.row {
      cell.password.text = dataParse[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String
      cell.name.text = dataParse[indexPath.row]["user"] as? String
    }

    print("Error")
    return cell
}
```